# Select columns from pivot table in BelongsToMany Relationship

Tags: laravel

I have this query that works perfectly but I would like it to select only the id and title of the post.

```
$posts = $this->section1->posts()
                ->with([
                    'survey' => function ($query) {
                        $query->withCount('totalSurveys');
                    },
                    'survey.surveyOptions',
                    'survey.totalSurveys.survey_option.color',
                    'image',
                    'categories:id,name,slug',
                ])
                ->withCount('comments')
                ->where('status', Post::PUBLICADO)
                ->orderBy('order', 'ASC')
                ​->get();
```

**section model**

```
class Section extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

I tried selecting the fields through the relationship but it didn't work:

```
public function posts()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class)->select(['id', 'title']);
        }
```

Can anyone help me ? thank you

Comment: If you really want only id and title of posts, then remove also all realtionships. I think this should work.
`$posts = $this->section1->posts()->select(['id', 'title'])->where('status', Post::PUBLICADO)->orderBy('order', 'ASC')->get();`

Comment: But I also need relationships. Besides, adding the select() to the query doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
$sectionId = $this->section1->id;

$posts = Post::whereHas('sections', function (Builder $query) use ($sectionId) {
        $query->where('id', $sectionId);
    })
    ->with([
        'survey' => function ($query) {
            $query->withCount('totalSurveys');
        },
        'survey.surveyOptions',
        'survey.totalSurveys.survey_option.color',
        'image',
        'categories:id,name,slug',
    ])
    ->withCount('comments')
    ->select(['id', 'title'])
    ->where('status', Post::PUBLICADO)
    ->orderBy('order', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```